# XML::Simple, вывести такую же XML как на входе

Tags: perl

```
my $xml = XMLin($flash_xml, KeepRoot => 1);

open(my $fh, '>', $flash_xml) or die "can't open file '$flash_xml' $!";
print $fh XMLout($xml, KeepRoot => 1, XMLDecl => '<?xml version="1.0"?>');
close($fh);
```

на входе:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <Persons>
        <person name="a" any="qwe"/>
        <person name="b" any="weq"/>
        <person name="c" any="wqe"/>
    </Persons>
</root>
```

на выходе:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <Persons name="person">
    <a any="qwe" />
    <b any="weq" />
    <c any="wqe" />
  </Persons>
</root>
```

Как сохранить изначальный формат?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хм (опустим вопрос "нафига?"...). В первом приближении это опция [GroupTags=>{Persons=>person}](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#GroupTags-grouping-tag-grouped-tag-in-out---handy). Правда, она добавит `name` к `Persons`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <Persons name="person">
    <person name="a" any="qwe" />
    <person name="b" any="weq" />
    <person name="c" any="wqe" />
  </Persons>
</root>
```

Но если нужно более глубоко влиять на форматирование при выводе (снова опустим вопрос "нафига?"...),то нужно что-то другое вместо XML::Simple. Или удовлетвориться дефолтным поведением [XML::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::DOM):

```
use XML::DOM;
my $parser = new XML::DOM::Parser;
my $doc = $parser->parsefile ('1.xml');
print $doc->toString;
```

Выведет:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <Persons>
        <person name="a" any="qwe"/>
        <person name="b" any="weq"/>
        <person name="c" any="wqe"/>
    </Persons>
</root>
```

---

Судя по уточнению в комментарии, основная проблема в "вольном" обращении с `id` (и, возможно, с аналогичными ключами). На самом деле эта ситуация [однозначно описана в документации](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#KeyAttr-list-in-out---important):

> Note 1: The default value for 'KeyAttr' is ['name', 'key', 'id']. If
>   you do not want folding on input or unfolding on output you must set
>   this option to an empty list to disable the feature.

То есть вам нужно:

```
my $xml = XMLin($flash_xml, KeepRoot=>1, KeyArttr=>{});
```

После чего никакого "раскрытия" элементов происходить не будет. Плюс обязательно см. там же **Note 2** (мне заниматься художественным чтением манов вслух уже лень).

Comment: Дело в том, что это лишь пример, по факту я получаю сложную xml в которой удаляю\добавляю ноды, с которой потом идет работа уже в c++ с уже заданным форматом, оказывается есть еще одна проблема что все `id=""`, он заменил на `name=""` :(

Т.е. никак нельзя заставить XML::Simple вывести в таком же формате, в котором получает?

Comment: @arukasa, а документацию читать не попробовали? См. обновление ответа.

Comment: `KeyAttr => {}` оказалось достаточно.

Огромное ВАМ спасибо, все получилось, я читал, но это пропустил.