# Как найти и заменить выражение в файле?

Tags: perl

Мне нужно найти и заменить слово или выражение в файле, на свое, разумеется. Например, у меня есть файл `file.xml`:

```
<title name="Article">Article</title>
<title name="article_1">text Article text</title>
```

Мне нужно заменить слово `Article` только внутри скобок `><`. Я пробовал работать с `perl` через `cmd`:

```
perl -p -i -e "s/article/myText/gi" file.xml
```

но при составлении выражения замены с регулярными выражениями получается так, что происходит замена не одного слова, а всего, что я указал. Мне нужно, чтобы производилась замена только одного слова - `article`.

Comment: приведенный Вами пример заменяет именно слово article (маленькими буквами). Подробнее объясните в чем именно проблема

Comment: Мне нужно заменить слово `article` с любым регистром (поправил пост) по маске. Если выставлять маску по скобкам, что-то вроде `s/\s*>\s*article\s*<\s*`, то происходит замена всей маски, а мне нужно заменить только одно слово.

Comment: видимо что от типа `\s*>\s*\Karticle(?=\s*<\s*)` ? только букву `i` еще после `g` поставьте что бы она без учете регистра была

Comment: Хорошо. Таким способом я получаю строку `<title name="Article"myText/title>`
вместо нужной `<title name="Article">myText</title>`

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону переменных, хранящих совпадения с каждой частью паттерна: $1, $2, ...

Comment: Да, нужно добавить что-то перед myText и после, но я не знаю что именно. Конкретно $1 не работает

Comment: @SergeyMolyak Очень странно. только, что проверил в консоли `perl -p -i -e "s/>\Karticle(?=<)/myText/gi" file.xml` он заменил только слово и оставил все угловые скобки на месте. \s* расставить по желанию. Неужели у вас это не работет ? Тест: https://regex101.com/r/lI1zE3/1

Comment: Огромное спасибо за подсказку, доработал, теперь работает как надо -> https://regex101.com/r/lI1zE3/2 - меняет нужный мне текст внутри скобок `><`. Только вот еще один момент. Таким способом меняется только одно совпадение в строке. Если написать 2 раза article внутри скобок `><`, то только второе совпадение заменится. Как сделать так, чтобы все совпадения изменялись?

Comment: А между теми article внутри скобок что должно быть ? Выражение совершенно по другому должно выглядеть если например вам надо заменить внутри произвольного текса, т.е. типа <title>some text article some text article</title>. Вам именно это надо ?

Comment: Внутри скобок может быть совершенно произвольный текст. Там может быть просто 3 повторяющихся слова article, которые нужно заменить, не меняя при этом слово article в атрибутах тега <title>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(\G|>)[^<>]*?\Karticle/myText/gi' file.xml
```

`\G` - обозначает точку входа в выражение после последней произведенной замены. Таким образом `(\G|>)` будет искать последующий текст сразу после конца тега и после произведенной замены продолжит искать тот же текст с точки где эта замена произошла. `\K` - обозначает точку, все выражение до которой считается предварительной проверкой в само совпадение для замены не входящее.

[Пример на regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qU0xS2/3)

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Printer;
use XML::Simple;

my $xml = XMLin( 'data.xml' );
p $xml;
replace_content( $xml, 'article', 'myText' );
p $xml;
say XMLout( $xml );

sub replace_content
{
  my ($xml, $what, $to) = @_;
  # доп. проверки пропущены для наглядности
  if( ref $xml eq 'HASH' ) {
      $xml->{content} =~ s/$what/$to/igs if $xml->{content};
      replace_content( $xml->{$_}, $what, $to ) for keys $xml;
  }
}
```

**NB!** Вывод `XMLout()` может отличаться от оригинала. Если это критично - можно поиграться с ключами (см. [документацию](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple), вопрос "[XML::Simple, вывести такую же XML как на входе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543351)" и т.д.).

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i-n -p -e "s!>article<!>word<!igs" file.xml
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: на прочтении мануала